# How to set the path in Jupyter Lab to find a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, command

I'm getting a `FileNotFound` error in JupyterLab on macOS when I issue a command to read a CSV file.

This was working until yesterday, when I upgraded to Python 3.9. Now it appears that my path has changed, and Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab can no longer find files (CSVs, in this instance) stored in the same directory as the notebooks are stored.

I've read that I need to list the path, when I run `read_csv`, but I've done that and essentially get the same error (though with less Traceback).

This screenshot shows my command and the output (I'm in JupyterLab 2.2.6 on macOS Catalina):

[image: Screenshot of FNF error]

I tried listing the path this way:

```
df_final = pd.read_csv('/Users/home_directory/df_trump_tweets_date_and_time_final_20jan2017_through_26sept2020')
```

And I tried:

```
df_final = pd.read_csv('Users/home_directory/df_trump_tweets_date_and_time_final_20jan2017_through_26sept2020')
```

Each of those returns the same Traceback:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/home_directory/df_trump_tweets_date_and_time_final_20jan2017_through_26sept2020'

Am I making a mistake in how I'm listing the path? I know I could change the path, but I'm a noob and I'm more than a little scared to do that as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following code:

```py
df_final = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/home_directory/df_trump_tweets_date_and_time_final_20jan2017_through_26sept2020')
```

or

```py
pd.read_csv('/Users/home_directory/df_trump_tweets_date_and_time_final_20jan2017_through_26sept2020.csv')
```

or you should ensure the file is exist in the directory though the following code

```
ls /Users/home_directory/  # list the file and directory in the `home_directory`
```

Comment: Thank you, Bytesmith.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very embarrassed to point out that the error is the result of my leaving ".csv" out of the file name. That's it. Just carelessness.

On the positive side (and thank you Bytesmith) I learned that "df_final = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/joelprestonsmith/df_trump_tweets_date_and_time_final_20jan2017_through_26sept2020.csv')" also works in reading the file (when the correct, full, name is used.

But I don't understand what the "r" does, versus running the command minus the r.

I also learned a lot understanding paths, finding out which version of python is running in which environment (in Lab, versus the default python at the command line).

Comment: the 'r' in front of string tell the compile the string is raw string and do not escape anything. ps. accoding the Code of Conduct, please don't use the answer to post your opinions , you can edit the description of the question or  add comment . hope to help you